# jquery slide up for hidden element

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(function(){
    $('#twittercontent').hide();
});

$('#twitter').on('click', '.hvtext',function(){
    $('#twittercontent').slideUp('slow');
});

#twittercontent {
    background:rgba(255,0,0,1);
    width:320px;
    height:310px;
    display:block;
    z-index:205;
    position:absolute;
    top:5em;
    left:20em;
}
```

The div 'twittercontent' is a div that is called when clicking '.hvtext'. It is hidden while not clicked and when called I want it to slide up.

.slideDown works but .slideUp does not. I'd prefer it to slide up, is there any reason why .slideUp isn't working in this case?

Comment: slide up is used to hide the element not display it

Comment: since the content is already hidden it won't do anything....

Comment: is there anyway other way to create the slideup effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to Arun P Johny's comment, you have to work out what you're trying to achieve with this

JS works with DOM elements, so it can only perform CSS-based styling in a way which is conducive with HTML principles (I.E it cannot hide a hidden element)

---

**JSFiddle**

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3E6f/) for you

I don't really get what you're trying to do, but I guess you could use the [SlideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function, like this:

```
$('#twitter').on('click', '.hvtext',function(){
    $('#twittercontent').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear. I have a bottom navigation and the click event would have this hidden element 'slide up' and cover the page. I was just wondering if this was possible (i realise the limitations of slideUp) I was hoping there was a 'visual' alternative.

Comment: So when you mention "cover the page", basically making it an "overlay"?

Comment: mm kinda, in my situation it's to cover an already existing div. But the idea of 'sliding up' from a bottom navigation is what I mean

Comment: I still don't get you I'm afraid. Do you mean a [fly-in](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/adcvK/) type effect?

Comment: not quite. I just want a similar effect to 'slideDown' but in a 'slideUp' except that which applies to an element hidden. I want the hidden div to 'rise up' from the bottom navigation in a 'slide' style

Comment: So you want it to fly & slide at the same time, to a particular position on the screen?

Comment: yea (i think) ill try with your fly-in example you linked